# How to verify JWT signature using Java 1.4

Tags: java, json

I am working on a legacy IBM WCS e-Commerce application which is built on JDK 1.4.

I have requirement verify a JWT token by calling an external JSON Web Key Set (JWKS) (/.well-known/jwks.json) end-point to retrieve the public key and use the verify the token signature and retrieve the Claims.

Below is the code using Java 8 which provides the RSA Public Key based on the 'n' and 'e' values from JSON Web Key.

```
public PublicKey getPublicKey() throws InvalidPublicKeyException {
    try {
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1,Base64.decodeBase64(stringValue("n")));
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, 
Base64.decodeBase64(stringValue("e")));
        return kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        ......
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        ......
    }
}
```

Later I use that KEY to verify the signature,

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(getPublicKey(decodeToken(token)))
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
```

Is it possible to achieve the same above 2 functionalities using Java 1.4 (or) at least using Java 5? Please guide, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good cryptographic support did not land in Java until version 8, with fairly good support in version 7.

But it should be noted that [according to the 1.0 spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation), if the JWT was directly obtained from the issuer via a TLS connection, the token signature can be assumed to be valid:

> 3.1.3.7.  ID Token Validation
>
> Clients MUST validate the ID Token in the Token Response in the following manner:
>
> ...
>
> 6. If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in [the code] flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature. The Client MUST validate the signature of all other ID Tokens according to JWS using the algorithm specified in the JWT `alg` Header Parameter. The Client MUST use the keys provided by the Issuer.
>
> ...

BTW, thanks for your question, it actually answered my question regarding how to check a JWT signature.